# How do I prove the triangle inequality for the Euclidean norm?

Tags: normed-spaces

If $V$ = $\mathbb{R^n}$, we have **x** = ($x_1,x_2,...,x_n$) $\in$ $V$ where

||**x**|| $=$ $\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2}$.

How am I supposed to prove that for **v**,**w** $\in$ $V$ that ||**v** + **w**|| $\leq$ ||**v**|| + ||**w**||?

My start of proof:
$\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n (v + w)_j^2}$ = $\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2 + 2 <v,w> + y_j^2}$

But have no clue where to go from here

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No because that is the distance between two points in Euclidean n-space; and idk if I can adjust it for that

Comment: Use Minkowski inequality; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: Usually we use the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must recall that $f(x)=x^{2}$ is a monotone function in $x\in[0,\infty)$, so $x<y\iff x^{2}<y^{2}$, with $x,y\geq0$.

Now,

$$||v+y||^{2}=\sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2 + 2\left\langle v,w\right\rangle + \sum_{j=1}^n y_j^2\leq \sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2 + 2||v|| \cdot||y|| + \sum_{j=1}^n y_j^2
=(||v||+||y||)^2$$

because the inner product is always zero or positive and $\left\langle v,w\right\rangle=||v|| \cdot||y||\cdot \cos(\theta)$.

So, $||v+y||\leq ||v||+||y||$.

Comment: I recognised the other part but it's proving the inequality the wrong way which is a huge issue and won't help with the solution

Comment: I realised I made an error while writing. You are supposed take squares, and (v+w)^2=v^2+w^2+2vw. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think @JoseCarlosSantos is sort of right that this question is answered in the only answer to the proposed duplicate he linked to in the comments. However, seeing this is not obvious to all. So, start with C-S, which is true for all sequences of real numbers:

$$ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} v_j w_j \right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} {v_j}^{\ 2}\right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} {w_j}^{\ 2}\right) $$

$$ \iff 2 \left\lvert \sum_{j=1}^{n} v_j w_j \right\rvert  \leq 2\sqrt{ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} {v_j}^{\ 2}\right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} {w_j}^{\ 2}\right) } $$

$$ \implies \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( v_j + w_j\right)^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n} {v_j}^{\ 2} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} {w_j}^{\ 2} + 2 \sqrt{ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} {v_j}^{\ 2}\right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} {w_j}^{\ 2}\right) } $$

$$ \iff \sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( v_j + w_j\right)^2 } \leq \sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} {v_j}^{\ 2} } + \sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} {w_j}^{\ 2} }. $$